# Как зациклить выполнение кода?

Tags: python, циклы, pyrogram

У меня есть часть кода:

```
app.start()

targets_file = open('targets.txt', 'r').readlines()
targets = [target for target in targets_file]
for target_user in targets:
    import pyrogram

    try:
        app.send_message(target_user, msg)
        # time.sleep(randint(2, 6))
    except pyrogram.errors.bad_request_400.PeerFlood as e:
        print(e)
        pass
    except pyrogram.errors.bad_request_400.UsernameNotOccupied as e:
        print(e)
        pass
    except:
        pass

app.stop()
```

Мне нужно зациклить его чтобы он повторялся каждый 10 минут. Пытался через while True - не получается. Что думаете? Вот как я пробовал:

```
app.start()

targets_file = open('targets.txt', 'r').readlines()
targets = [target for target in targets_file]
for target_user in targets:
    import pyrogram
    While True:
        try:
            app.send_message(target_user, msg)
            # time.sleep(randint(2, 6))
        except pyrogram.errors.bad_request_400.PeerFlood as e:
            print(e)
            pass
        except pyrogram.errors.bad_request_400.UsernameNotOccupied as e:
            print(e)
            pass
        except:
            pass
    time.sleep(600)
app.stop()
```

Comment: А что не получилось? Цикл while вполне себе решение, только вы не писали про задержку в 10 минут

Comment: Когда использую цикл while True, программа почему-то не работает

Comment: А что за `app`? Добавьте в вопрос (кнопка `править`) пример использования того `while`, хочется посмотреть при каком виде оно не работает. **UPD.** хотя я понял, вы используете клиент телеграмма и у того есть цикл обработки событий, поэтому добавляя свой цикл, вы блочите работу клиента телеграмма. Это логично. Нужно в отдельном потоке запускать цикл `while`, используйте `threading.Thread`

Comment: написал как я пробовал, а как использовать threads?

Comment: @Kowl https://habr.com/ru/post/149420/ многопоточность на питоне

Comment: Тут фор и вайл местами поменять

Answer (score 0):

Решил всё сам без thread. Нужно обернуть код в функцию (я назвал её app1) и достаточно в конце кода дописать:

```
t=1
while t == 1:
    app1()
    time.sleep(300)
```

И всё получится.

Comment: Что именно вы обернули в app1? Думаю, тоже самое было бы, если бы вы обернули тот же код не в функцию, а в цикл while True.

Comment: к сожалению ваш ответ не правильный, было бы так легко сделал бы давно. Единственный вариант обернуть в функцию код и дать ей время через которое она будет повторятся.

Comment: Если не смог сделать, то не значит что "неправильный". Придумал какой-то костыль и решил, что так правильно.

Answer (score 0):

0. Само разумеющееся, но на всякий случай напишу, что нельзя забывать про import time
1. Цикл while будет работать и каждые 10 минут, если строку time.sleep(600) указать внутри цикла while, а не за его пределами, как указано во 2 фрагменте кода, если же тебе надо принудить цикл for к повторению через каждые 10 минут, то while прописывай поверх for, а time.sleep(600) в конце цикла while напротив for.
2. На всякий случай опять же, в коде должно писаться не While, а while (с маленькой буквы).
   Прокомментировать работу с pyrogram не могу, ибо не доводилось с ней работать.